# JRuby: data type in deserialized input stream throws casting error

Tags: java, serialization, casting, jruby

This results in a `java.lang.ClassCastException` error. I'm new to both Java and JRuby, which is not helping my chances.

#### java-side code (simplified)

```
public ParallelTopicModel implements Serializable {
    private void readObject (ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException          {
      ... bunch of stuff deserializing objects ...
    }

public static ParallelTopicModel read (File f) throws Exception {
    ParallelTopicModel goodThing = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream(f));
    goodThing = (ParallelTopicModel) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return goodThing;
    }
}
```

#### jruby-side code

```
my_jruby_object = ParallelTopicModel::read(java.io.File.new(some_filename))
```

The last statement throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException`, claiming that *another* java class (`InstanceList`) cannot be cast to `ParallelTopicModel`. I haven't delved into the java-side code very deeply, but I'm guessing that `InstanceList` is the type of the first object serialized in the file I'm trying to read, based on what I see in the code that's writing the serialization.

A lightly-edited stack trace from my IDE looks like this:

11007: Resumed Thread #
cc/mallet/topics/ParallelTopicModel.java:1997:in `read': java.lang.ClassCastException: cc.mallet.types.InstanceList cannot be cast to cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel
    from java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606:in`invoke'
    from /home/tom/RubymineProjects/CaseTagger/baby-jruby.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /home/tom/RubymineProjects/CaseTagger/baby-jruby.rb:54:in`(root)'
    from org/jruby/debug/RubyDebugger.java:204:in `debug_load'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in`load'
    from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `(root)'

I've tried a number of JRuby-ish tricks using to_java and its ilk, but it appears that the objection is to the type of the data being returned.  The Java code is (obviously) not mine, and I am certainly no Java programmer, but it looks as though the purpose of the cast is to force the use of ParallelTopicModel's readObject method, but Jruby is interpreting it as trying to cast the type of the first object out of the serialization.

Any thoughts?

#### (1 week later) Appears to be a JRuby problem

I've tried a number of things that take advantage of JRuby's ability to (eg.) call masked and private methods, coerce typing, etc.  None have worked.  I've also looked through a number of Java tutorials on the use of ObjectInputStream (though in a less-informed way, because while I'm not much of a Ruby programmer I'm no kind of Java programmer at all).  I've concluded that the use of casting in this example is a Java idiom that JRuby doesn't understand:

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
deserializedObjectOfClassBlah = (Blah) ois.readObject();

The effect of the cast using (Blah) in Java is for Java to look for, and invoke, a private Blah.readObject method.  The effect in JRuby is for JRuby to try to type-cast the first non-primitive object it finds in the stream.

Thoughts very welcome, if anyone has encountered and solved this. I'd still like to find a solution.

Comment: Could you also post the entire stack trace and specify on which line it occurs?

Comment: Thanks, but edit your question with the stacktrace instead of writing a comment.